# Set UIImageView From Modal To Another Controller

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, modal-dialog, uiimage

I have a form the user is filling out, and I present a modal with images for them to choose from. I am attempting to set a UIImage in the original controller from the modal, but the problem is it's nil.

What is the best way to set it? The viewDidLoad doesn't seem to trigger on dismissal of a modal, which is how I'm getting rid of it, and neither does the viewWillAppear. When can I set the image?

My Code right now:

```
    //Collection view choosing deal background
    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var chosenNumber: Int?

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)

        if(self.restorationIdentifier == "NewDeal") {
            if(chosenNumber != nil) {
                newDealBackgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "food_\(chosenNumber!)")
            }
        }
    }

extension BusinessOwnerVC: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        //self.newDealBackgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "food_\(indexPath.row + 1)")!
        chosenNumber = indexPath.row + 1

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much experimentation, here's what I found works for me. All I wanted was to access and update a view controller (of the same kind) under a modal I am presenting. Turns out my previous VC was still active, so all I had to do was pass a reference to that VC into the modal, and then I could change its properties.

```
let modal = UIStoryboard.init(name: "BusinessOwner", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DealBackgroundSelection") as! BusinessOwnerVC

modal.newDealView = self // This is a weak var of BusinessOwnerVC? declared in the view controller itself

present(modal, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And then when I was ready to dismiss that modal:

```
self.newDealView!.updateDealImage(number: indexPath.row + 1)
```

updateDealImage was just a function I created to handle all the update. And that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If your presentation style is `fullScreen` … then your willAppear will be called

```
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```

but if you dont want full screen presentation Make yourself the presentation controller's delegate and override `presentationControllerDidDismiss(_:`).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            print("viewWillAppear")
        }

        @IBAction func show(_ sender: Any) {
            let newViewController = NewViewController()
            //set delegate of UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate to self
            newViewController.presentationController?.delegate = self
            present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    extension UIViewController: UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate {
        public func presentationControllerDidDismiss( _ presentationController: UIPresentationController) {
            if #available(iOS 13, *) {
                //Call viewWillAppear only in iOS 13
                viewWillAppear(true)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I do believe I'm implemented your code properly, but the presentationControllerDidDimiss doesn't ever get called. I'm instantiating a specific VC as my class VC, if that matters.
What else could I try?

Comment: Are you confirming to delegate ?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Here's my code:


`@IBAction func presentImages(_ sender: Any) {

        let modal = UIStoryboard.init(name: "BusinessOwner", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DealBackgroundSelection")
        
        modal.presentationController?.delegate = self

        present(modal, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }`

`extension BusinessOwnerVC: UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate {
    func presentationControllerDidDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) {
        print("did dismiss")
    }
}`

Comment: extension is in same class where you confirm delegate ?

Comment: Yes, it's in the same class. It seems like I'm missing something. All I want is to run a function when a modal dismisses, and the next VC is going to appear. The delegate seems like a good option, but I must be doing something wrong. Is there any other approach I could try?

Comment: So it appears to trigger the DidDismiss function if I manually swipe it away, but it doesn't when I call the function dismiss or popViewController.

Comment: we can solve it using closures .... can you do that ? or i need to provide how it works ?

Comment: Is a closure like a completion handler? I’ve tried using those with the dismiss function, but my UIImage object isn’t available when the dismiss function completes.